# HTML frames example

Tags: html

Will this work?

```
<html>
<body>
<center>
<frameset rows="50%,50%">
<frame src="images.html">
<frameset>
<form action="abc.html">
<input type="submit" name="abc page" value="abc page">
</form>
</frameset>
</frameset>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I give the code as above, like giving a html link page in a frame, and in other frame, a HTML code.

Comment: Have you not tried it yourself?

Comment: I am using eclipse IDE, in a project.. eclipse is not executing frames, as it is not HTML 5. So I've to copy the code and execute. SO i need other html docs too. So i didnt try

Comment: Well then try it and see if it works, simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can. The `<frameset>` tag defines a frameset.

The `<frameset>` element holds one or more  elements. Each  element can hold a separate document.

Answer (score 0):

[`<frameset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) and [`<frame>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) are both deprecated. Avoid using them.

Use an [`<iframe>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) instead.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kqo9yhk5/

HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```